# Referencing a .NET 2 assembly in a project targeting .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently using TeeChart Lite (the free version of teechart). I would like to use it in my WPF project however the downloadable free version is only available for .NET 2.0 therefore I get the following error:

> Warning   1   The referenced assembly
>   "TeeChart.Lite" could not be resolved
>   because it has a dependency on
>   "System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which
>   is not in the currently targeted
>   framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".
>   Please remove references to assemblies
>   not in the targeted framework or
>   consider retargeting your project.

Is it safe to just add the assembly System.Design, Version 4.0.0.0 even though it is not part of the targeted framework? Or is there something else I can do to get it working in .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have Visual Studio available to test, but it's probably one of these two things:

More likely, you just need to reference System.Design.dll, [which is a standalone DLL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/11/11/256174.aspx).

Less likely: as the error message states, you are targeting the 4.0 *client framework*, which is the default for new projects in VS2010.  Go to your project properties and reference the *full* 4.0 framework, which might solve the problem.

The actual solution may require combining both steps.

Comment: It was the "Less Likely" option that solved the problem which makes sense as System.Design version 4.0.0.0 is part of the .NET 4 framework. Thanks :)